# How to apply Fancybox to DIVs

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Brief background: I just started getting into coding websites.  My current website is [jamesendres.com](http://www.jamesendres.com) and what I want to do is use Fancybox to move my div called project, left & right depending on which arrow is clicked inside of its' parent div projectContainer. I've read through the documentation and I feel that their examples lack in regards to beginner coders. Additionally I extensively searched Google and SO. my question is if someone would be able to point me in the right direction of how to actually apply Fancybox to my current website.

What I wanted to do:
when right arrow is click move to the right:
same goes for left respectively.
Then update the pager position i.e. the 01/02

Also if anyone notices any redundant coding techniques or have any constructive criticism I am plenty open to it. Good/practical coding style

Comment: A better place for general code review is http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: They have assumed u know what jquery u have :)

Comment: I included the most up to date version of jquery.  Will that not work for Fancybox? Or in fancybox is the version of jquery hardcoded in there